# Routing based on the request uri host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So the basic premise to this problem is that I have a single hosted webspace which came with two domain names. I am unsure how to configure routing in asp.net mvc so that the first thing I would check would be this host in the request object so that I can more user traffic to two separate parts of my website.

For example:

```
http://www.mywebsite1.com/products/14

http://www.mywebsite2.com/products/14
```

How do you route so that those two url's above end up returning two different pages based on the context of the host used in the request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom view engine that will look at the URL post controller execute and select the correct view.

Check this out for more info: [Asp.Net Themes](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use some kind of URL rewriting in IIS7 or whatever you use, because it can access the domain name part too. For example you can create a rewrite method that injects the domain name into the url, like:

http//www.example1.org/Something/1 --> http//www.example1.org/example1/Something/1
http//www.example2.org/Something/1 --> http//www.example2.org/example2/Something/1

And because now the domain name is in the URL string, you can use the default routing engine to send this information to the controllers or do something else.